# Is the polynomial $x^2 + x+2$ primitive?

Tags: coding-theory

Let $F_5$ be the field of integers modulo $5$.

I am trying to find out if $x^2 + x + 2$ is primitive or not.

So first we see that the divisors of $24$ are $1,2,3,4,6,8,12$.

We find $$x^2=-x-2$$
$$x^3=-x^2-2x$$x
$$x^4 =(-x-2)^2=x^2+4x+4=-2x+2$$

> How does $x^2+4x+4=-2x+2$?
>
> How does $x^6=x^2-4x+4=x^2+x-1$?
>
> How does $x^8=-x^2+2x-1=-2x+1$?
>
> From this how can we deduce that the order of $\alpha$ is not
> $1,2,3,4,6,8$?Is it because they dont equal $1$?
>
> If $x^6=2$ how does $x^{12}=-1$

We can see that $x^{24}=1$ so the polynomial is in fact primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial $2+X+X^2$ is the "default primitive polynomial" for $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$, see [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gfprimdf.html). Regarding your last question: If $X^6=2$ then $X^{12}=2^2=-1$ over a field of characteristic $5$.
We have
$$
X^3=-X^2-2X=-X+2,
$$
and
$$
X^4=X^2+4X+4=(-X-2)+4X+4=3X+2=-2X+2.
$$

Comment: Why does $X^2+4X+2=-2X+2$?

Comment: It is not equal. There is a mistake in your calculation $X^4=(-X-2)^2=(X+2)^2=X^2+4X+4$.

Comment: Ok corrected thank, so how does $X^2+4X+4=-2X+2$?